# Can property accessors have prototypes in Javascript

Tags: javascript

My question follows this code sample:

```
// Factory Constructor
function CarFactory() {
}

CarFactory.prototype.info = function () {
    console.log("This car has " + this.doors + " doors and a " + this.engine_capacity + " liter engine");
};

// the static factory method
CarFactory.make = function (type) {
    var constr = type;
    var car;
    CarFactory[constr].prototype = new CarFactory();
    // create a new instance
    car = new CarFactory[constr]();
    return car;
};

CarFactory.Compact = function () {
    this.doors = 4;
    this.engine_capacity = 2;
};

CarFactory.Sedan = function () {
    this.doors = 2;
    this.engine_capacity = 2;
};

CarFactory.SUV = function () {
    this.doors = 4;
    this.engine_capacity = 6;
};

var golf = CarFactory.make('Compact');
var vento = CarFactory.make('Sedan');
var touareg = CarFactory.make('SUV');
golf.info(); //"This car has 4 doors and a 2 liter engine"
```

I understand how the prototype property is used to add additional properties to functions. However, in this code sample, the line of code that I find peculiar is this:

```
CarFactory[constr].prototype = new CarFactory();
```

Here, CarFactory[constr] is a property accessor. This could have been written like this:

```
CarFactory.Sedan.prototype = new CarFactory();
```

Sedan in this example is a property. But most examples I've seen up until now attach new properties or functions directly on the main object. For example:

CarFactory.prototype.manufacturer = new Manufacturer();

So is it true to state that the prototype property is used to add new properties or functions to either an existing property or function?

Comment: Assigning a `new CarFactory()` to the `.prototype` in every call to `make` is an absolutely horrible idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CarFactory.Sedan`, `CarFactory.Compact`, and `CarFactory.SUV` are all constructor functions (like `CarFactory` itself is). So they have a property called `prototype`, which refers to the object that will be used as the prototype of objects created via `new CarFactory.Sedan`, etc.

The fact that those functions (`Sedan`, `Compact`, `SUV`) are also referenced via properties on `CarFactory` makes no difference to the fact that they are constructor functions.

> So is it true to state that the prototype property is used to add new properties or functions to either an existing property or function?

It's true to say that the `prototype` property of a constructor function refers to the object that will be used as the prototype of objects created via `new` with that function. So  adding to that object adds features that will be available to those objects via prototypical inheritance.

---

That code has a couple of issues, though, particularly in the `make` function:

1. It doesn't make any sense to re-create a new `CarFactory` object and assign it to `CarFactory[constr].prototype` every time you call `make`. It's creating a new prototype for each object being created by `make`, which is pointless. The main purpose of prototypes is reuse.
2. In general, using `new Xyz` to create an object to put on another constructor's `prototype` property is usually part of an anti-pattern. (It's harmless in this case, `CarFactory` doesn't take any parameters; it's poor practice in the general case.)

I'd completely set up the car types (`Sedan`, etc.) rather than partially setting them up, and then reuse them. Here are **minimum** changes I'd make:

```js
var CarFactory = (function() {
    // Factory Constructor
    function CarFactory() {
    }

    // Prototype methods
    CarFactory.prototype.info = function() {
        console.log("This car has " + this.doors + " doors and a " + this.engine_capacity + " liter engine");
    };

    // The static factory method
    CarFactory.make = function(type) {
        var ctor = CarFactory[type];
        if (!ctor) {
            throw new Error("Unknown type '" + type + "'");
        }
        return new ctor();
    };

    // Function to create types of cars
    function makeCarType(ctor) {
        ctor.prototype = Object.create(CarFactory.prototype);
        ctor.prototype.constructor = ctor;
        return ctor;
    }

    // Types
    CarFactory.Compact = makeCarType(function() {
        this.doors = 4;
        this.engine_capacity = 2;
    });

    CarFactory.Sedan = makeCarType(function() {
        this.doors = 2;
        this.engine_capacity = 2;
    });

    CarFactory.SUV = makeCarType(function() {
        this.doors = 4;
        this.engine_capacity = 6;
    });

    return CarFactory;
})();

var golf = CarFactory.make('Compact');
var vento = CarFactory.make('Sedan');
var touareg = CarFactory.make('SUV');
golf.info(); //"This car has 4 doors and a 2 liter engine"
vento.info(); //"This car has 2 doors and a 2 liter engine"
touareg.info(); //"This car has 4 doors and a 6 liter engine"
```

More significant changes would probably be to use ES2015+ `class` syntax and do away with `CarFactory.make` entirely.

Comment: I copied this code from the book "Mastering Javascript". Concerning point 1: Yes I thought the same thing. Seems kind of senseless. But this example is to demonstrate the Factory pattern, so it would seem correct to use new CarFactory when setting the prototype. Without it, the Sedan object has no real connection to the CarFactory object. So even though CarFactory is being recreated each time with make, it does guarantee that each car type has its own instance. I think that is what is being accomplished.

Comment: My real question though was whether CarFactory[constr].prototype = new CarFactory(); is being used on a property.  You actually answered this by indicating that it is really referring to the constructor for each car type. So in reality, even though this is a property accessor, the property accessor is really referencing a constructor. In other words, it isn't true that prototypes can be used for properties. They can only be used for functions or constructors.

Comment: Your code example does appear to be better while maintaining the factory pattern. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @AndroidDev: Just FWIW, I'm...unconvinced...of that code as an example of the Factory pattern. :-) Re your second comment: You have to be careful with your terminology: The `prototype` property of a constructor function is not "a prototype," it's just a property referring to an object. **If** you use `new` with that constructor function, then that object becomes the prototype of the new object created. But yes, `CarFactory[const]` retrieves a reference to a constructor function, so then using its `prototype` property is using the `prototype` property of a constructor.

Comment: As a unrelated question, each of the car types has two properties: doors and engine_capacity. Every time you create a new car type, you have to duplicate these properties. But if you forget to include one of those properties, at some point, the code will probably break. Is there a way in Javascript to avoid that? Some way to ensure that when you create a new car type you are guaranteeing that you have included all the properties of that are common to all car types?

Comment: Incidentally, I ran your code. The objects created for golf, vento and touareg  are identical to those created by the code I posted. The only difference is that the code I posted is smaller in size ;-) Still, I like your better because the car types are included as part of the CarFactory function.

Comment: @AndroidDev: With ES2015+, you could have constructors accepting params for those properties, with default values.

Comment: @AndroidDev: *"The objects created for golf, vento and touareg are identical to those created by the code I posted."* Yes, but if you make *another* `Sedan`, it will share a prototype with `vento`. The code is more memory-efficient. *"The only difference is that the code I posted is smaller in size"* Only superficially, and only because it correctly sets `constructor` on the prototype, which the original code doesn't, and ensures that it doesn't create a global `makeCarType`. Lines of code is not a good measure of, well, nearly anything. :-)